# Выскакивает ошибка: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Нужно вывести сумму всех четных чисел:

```
numbers = (9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
i = 0
for x in numbers:
  if x % 2 == 0:
    while int(x) > i:
      i += 2
      print(sum(i))
```

На `print(sum(i))` Выскакивает ошибка: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидали, передавая в функцию sum одно число?

Comment: А сумма всех чётных чисел выводится легко в одну строку: `print(sum(x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 0))`

Comment: Очень странный код. Зачем-то numbers это кортеж, а не список; зачем-то int берётся от уже числа, ну и да, непонятно, зачем sum от одного числа.

Comment: @CrazyElf, предположим, что человек учится. Разве это плохо, что есть попытки что-либо сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = [9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
s = 0
for num in numbers:
  if not x % 2:
      s += 2
print(s)
```

Либо так можно

```
numbers = [9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
s = sum(x for x in numbers if not x%2)
```